# Android support and extra setup with ivy

Tags: android, ivy

How to configure my **ivysettings.xml** file so that ivy can resolve the Android extra and support libraries that are deployed in `ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository` ?

At the end, I would like to be able to add those libraries with

```
    <dependency
        name="support-v4"
        org="com.android.support"
        rev="19.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to go (`ANDROID_HOME` is an environment variable that points to your android SDK):

```
<ivysettings>
    ...
    <properties environment="env" />
    <property name="android.repo" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support" />
    ...
    <resolvers>
        ... your resolvers ...
        <filesystem name="android-local" checkmodified="true">
            <ivy pattern="${android.repo}/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="${android.repo}/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="${android.repo}/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision]-sources.[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="${android.repo}/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision]-javadoc.[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
        <chain name="local-chain">
            ... ref to your resolvers ...
            <resolver ref="android-local" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```